# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'WebElement' and 'float'

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I keep on getting this error, however it is working for other items, just not this one

```
BarthemlowaBear = float(21.95)
```

```
def barthembear():
  driver.get(urlJellycatBarthemlowBear)
  time.sleep(1)
  name_ofBarthemlowaBear = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "base")
  price_printBarthemlowaBear = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "price")
  print(name_ofBarthemlowaBear.text)
  #element = wait.until(EC._element_if_visible(By.CLASS_NAME("price")));
  time.sleep(1)
  print(price_printBarthemlowaBear.text)
  price_printofBarthemlowaBear = float(price_printBarthemlowaBear.text.replace('£',''))
  if price_printofBarthemlowaBear < BarthemlowaBear:
   print("****************BUY***********************") 
  elif price_printBarthemlowaBear > BarthemlowaBear:
    print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!do not buy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
```

i am expecting the console to print out whether to buy the product based on if it is below the set float value i have given

Answer (score 0):

**You have to extract text from web_element and convert it to the float**

Example :

```
if float(price_printofBarthemlowaBear.text) < BarthemlowaBear:
```

Comment: extract numeric values from web_element only : You have to check whether extracted text contains only number else you can use re expression to extract numeric from it then only you will be able to convert it to the float